# How to generate the same random color in a table view for a table view row for another table view row?

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, uicolor

In my app, I click on a row and it expands another row underneath it. I want to generate a random color that when I click on a row, the row background turns that color and the expanded row underneath it turns the same color. How do I get the rows to generate the same random color?

I created a function to generate a random color and I call the function cell for row when isOpened is set to true and I call the same function for the cell that is expanded.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
    let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1  
    guard let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") else {return UITableViewCell()}  

    func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {  
        let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())  
        let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())  
        let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())  

        let randomColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)  

        return randomColor  
    }  

    if indexPath.row == 0 {  
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == false {  
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false  
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title  
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0  
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping  
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)  
            cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear  
            return cell1  
        }  
        else if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {  
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true  
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title  
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0  
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping  
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)  
            cell1.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()  
            return cell1  
        }  
        return cell1  
    } else {  
        cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]  
        cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0  
        cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping  
        cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)  
        cell1.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()  
        return cell1  
    }  
}
```

A random color is generated, but the expanded row generates a new color.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store the generated random colors. Every time you call generateRandomColor(), a new one is made. What I would do is create a dictionary of rows to colors.

```
var color: [Int: UIColor?] = [:]
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath determine if you already have a color for that row, and if not compute one:

```
if let color = colors[indexPath.row] {
    cell.backgroundColor = color
} else {
    colors[indexPath.row] = generateRandomColor()
}
```

Then in didSelectRowForIndexPath you can retrieve the randomColor using:

```
if let color = colors[indexPath.row] {
        // Expand the cell with the new color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert arter  local func:
let _color = generateRandomColor()
This value can be assigned, the elements that must have the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your section dataSource to include the color, like so:

```
struct SectionData {
    let title: String
    var color: UIColor?
}
```

Just before the line `if indexPath.row == 0 {`, add following

```
var backgroundColor: UIColor! = self.tableViewData[indexPath.section].color
if backgroundColor == nil {
    backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
    self.tableViewData[indexPath.section].color = backgroundColor
}
cell1.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
```

Now DELETE the other lines `cell1.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of these methods and I only found one that worked the way I wanted it to.

I had to modify my dataSource:

```
struct cellData {
var opened = Bool()
var title = String()
var sectionData = [String]()
var color: UIColor? = UIColor()
```

}

```
var tableViewData = [cellData]()

func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
let redValue = CGFloat(drand48())
let greenValue = CGFloat(drand48())
let blueValue = CGFloat(drand48())

let randomColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)

return randomColor
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
    guard let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") else {return UITableViewCell()}

    var backgroundColor: UIColor! = tableViewData[indexPath.section].color
    if backgroundColor == nil {
        backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].color = backgroundColor
    }
    cell1.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == false {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return cell1
        }
        else if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
            return cell1
        }
        return cell1
    } else {
        cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]
        cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        return cell1
    }
}
```