# How do I generate the same random color for a table view cell and expanded cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am creating an iOS app that when I click a table view row, the row expands into another row underneath it. I want to generate a random color for the table view rows background every time the row is clicked and I want the expanded row to be the same color as the clicked row. Every time the row is clicked, I want to generate a different random color. How do I do that?

I have tried putting my code for cellForRowAt in different spots and nothing seems to work.

```
func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
let redValue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
let greenValue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
let blueValue = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)

let randomColor = UIColor(red: redValue, green: greenValue, blue: blueValue, alpha: 1.0)

return randomColor
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
    guard let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") else {return UITableViewCell()}
    var sectionBackgroundColor: UIColor! = tableViewData[indexPath.section].color

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == false {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            return cell1
        }
        else if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
            if sectionBackgroundColor == nil {
                sectionBackgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
                tableViewData[indexPath.section].color = sectionBackgroundColor
            }
            cell1.backgroundColor = sectionBackgroundColor
            return cell1
        }
        return cell1
    } else {
        cell1.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]
        cell1.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell1.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell1.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        if sectionBackgroundColor == nil {
            sectionBackgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].color = sectionBackgroundColor
            cell1.backgroundColor = sectionBackgroundColor
        }
        else if sectionBackgroundColor != nil {
            sectionBackgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].color = sectionBackgroundColor
            cell1.backgroundColor = sectionBackgroundColor
        }
        cell1.backgroundColor = sectionBackgroundColor

        return cell1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        } else {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to click on a table view row and the row expands into a new row under the clicked row and the clicked row and expanded row generate the same random color every time the row is clicked, but the actual output is when I click the row, the row expands into a row under the clicked row and a random color is generated but both rows do not always generate the same color.

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521000/how-to-generate-the-same-random-color-in-a-table-view-for-a-table-view-row-for-a) which you even answered yourself?

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't execute the way I want it to. The previous way: Every time a row is clicked, it would generate the same random color for the clicked row and the expanded row but if I click it again to close it and then again to open it, it generates the same color for that row every time. I want it to generate a different random color every time a clicked row is expanded. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think your solution to have dictionary of colors is still right. All you need is after you use color from dictionary on expansion, replace dictionary value when you click on row to close it.